# Add link to allow editing profile from Meta

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, per-site-meta

Here's what happened to me just now:
[image: On my site meta profile: Where's the edit link?]

[image: Oh, I have to go to main]

(It took me an embarrassingly long time looking for an edit option on my meta profile to get to this step though)
[image: On my main profile: here it is! (the "Edit profile" option)]

So, I realize that it makes sense that we don't have separate profile information for site Meta accounts. And it also makes sense that we *do* have separate settings options for Meta (there are meta-only tags, people might be less interested in the questions and not want to receive email updates, etc.) But, instead of having the functionality change based on which site you're on, perhaps we could just make it so that you can edit your main-site profile from Meta? Or maybe keep them different, but make it a smaller difference: after clicking the "Edit profile and settings" horizontal tab on Meta, the vertical tab that you start out on is "Preferences" rather than "Edit Profile" by default, and if you click on "Edit Profile" you're automatically taken back to the main site page for that.